# How can I generate series of Pell numbers instead of a specific one in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

How do I use cons or other way to print a list of [Pell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number) till the Nth number?

```
(defun pellse (k)
   (if (or (zerop k) (= k 1))
       k
   (+ (* 2 (pellse (- k 1)))
      (pellse (- k 2)))))
 (print (pellse 7))
```

Comment: Hello @ziming-wang, you've already wrote the Lisp code to calculate the Nth Pell number, are you asking how to accumulate them into a list, such as `(pellse(1), pellse(2), ..., pellse(N))`

Comment: Exactly, ex. a list like this: (0 1 2 5 12 29 70) where the value of n is 6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to do it in a way that won’t be exponential:

```
(defun pells (n)
  (loop repeat n
    for current = 0 then next
    and next = 1 then (+ (* 2 next) current)
    collect current))
```

The time complexity to calculate the *n*th element given the two previous elements is O(log(*P<sub>n</sub>*)) where *P<sub>n</sub>* is the *n*th Pell number; you need log(*P<sub>n</sub>*) bits for the answer and log(*P<sub>n</sub>*) operations for the addition. We don’t actually need to work out what *P<sub>n</sub>* is: It is defined by a simple linear recurrence relation so the solution must be exponential so log(*P<sub>n</sub>*) = O(*n*). Therefore the complexity of calculating the first *n* Pell numbers is O(*n*n*) = O(*n*<sup>2</sup>).

One cannot<sup>[*****]</sup> do better than O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) as one must write O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) bits to represent all these numbers.

<sup>[*****]</sup> Although I very much doubt this, it might, in theory, be possible to represent the list in some more compact way by somehow sharing data.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an approach to solving this problem which works by defining an infinite stream of Pell numbers.  This is based on the ideas presented in [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html), and particularly [section 3.5](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#%_sec_3.5).  Everyone should read this book.

First of all we need to define a construct which will let us talk about infinite data structures.  We do this by *delaying* the evaluation of all but a finite part of them.  So start with a macro called `delay` which delays the evaluation of a form, returning a 'promise' (which is a function of course), and a function called `force` which forces the system to make good on its promise:

```
(defmacro delay (form)
  ;; Delay FORM, which may evaluate to multiple values.  This has
  ;; state so the delayed thing is only called once.
  (let ((evaluatedp-n (make-symbol "EVALUATEDP"))
        (values-n (make-symbol "VALUES")))
    `(let ((,evaluatedp-n nil) ,values-n)
       (lambda ()
         (unless ,evaluatedp-n
           (setf ,evaluatedp-n t
                 ,values-n (multiple-value-list
                            (funcall (lambda () ,form)))))
         (values-list ,values-n)))))

(defun force (promise)
  ;; force a promise (delayed thing)
  (funcall promise))
```

(This implementation is slightly overcomplex for our purposes, but it's what I had to hand.).

Now we'll use `delay` to define *streams* which are potentially infinite chains of conses.  There are operations on these corresponding to operations on conses but prefixed by `stream-`, and there is an object called `null-stream` which corresponds to `()` (and is in fact the same object in this implementation).

```
(defmacro stream-cons (car cdr)
  ;; a cons whose cdr is delayed
  `(cons ,car (delay ,cdr)))

(defun stream-car (scons)
  ;; car of a delayed cons
  (car scons))

(defun stream-cdr (scons)
  ;; cdr of a delayed cons, forced
  (force (cdr scons)))

(defconstant null-stream
  ;; the empty delayed cons
  nil)

(defun stream-null (stream)
  ;; is a delayed cons empty
  (eq stream null-stream))
```

Now define a function `pell-stream` which returns a stream of Pell numbers.  This function hand-crafts the first two elements of the stream, and then uses a generator to make the rest.

```
(defun pell-stream ()
  ;; A stream of Pell numbers
  (labels ((pell (pn pn-1)
             (let ((p (+ (* 2 pn) pn-1)))
               (stream-cons p (pell p pn)))))
    (stream-cons 0 (stream-cons 1 (pell 1 0)))))
```

And now we can simply repeatedly takes `stream-cdr` to compute Pell numbers.

```
(defun n-pell-numbers (n)
  (loop repeat n
        for scons = (pell-stream) then (stream-cdr scons)
        collect (stream-car scons)))
```

And now

```
> (n-pell-numbers 20)
(0
 1
 2
 5
 12
 29
 70
 169
 408
 985
 2378
 5741
 13860
 33461
 80782
 195025
 470832
 1136689
 2744210
 6625109)
```

Note that, in fact, `pell-stream` can be a global variable: it doesn't need to be a function:

```
(defparameter *pell-stream*
  (labels ((pell (pn pn-1)
             (let ((p (+ (* 2 pn) pn-1)))
               (stream-cons p (pell p pn)))))
    (stream-cons 0 (stream-cons 1 (pell 1 0)))))

(defun n-stream-elements (stream n)
  (loop repeat n
        for scons = stream then (stream-cdr scons)
        collect (stream-car scons)))
```

If we define a little benchmarking program:

```
(defun bench-pell (n)
  (progn (n-stream-elements *pell-stream* n) n))
```

Then it's interesting to see that this is clearly essentially a linear process (it slows down for later elements because the numbers get big and so operations on them take a long time), and that the stateful implementation of promises makes it *much* faster after the first iteration (at the cost of keeping quite a lot of bignums around):

```
> (time (bench-pell 100000))
Timing the evaluation of (bench-pell 100000)

User time    =        2.020
System time  =        0.803
Elapsed time =        2.822
Allocation   = 1623803280 bytes
441714 Page faults
100000

> (time (bench-pell 100000))
Timing the evaluation of (bench-pell 100000)

User time    =        0.007
System time  =        0.000
Elapsed time =        0.006
Allocation   = 1708248 bytes
0 Page faults
100000
```

Comment: Why choose to define streams instead of using series?

Comment: @DanRobertson: because 'here's how you can construct this interesting solution using basic language constructs' is more interesting, to me, than 'here's this vast, opaque, optimised tool which will solve the problem'.  Of course, I used `loop` thus kind of destroying my own argument.

Comment: @DanRobertson can series be used to define an extensible object like the return value of `(pell-stream)` here? or will it always run from the start again, on each new invocation?

Comment: @DanRobertson: that being said I'd welcome an answer that uses series!

Comment: @WillNess so the streams defined here are like a Haskell list (except that the cars are always forced) in that the computations are stored in memory as they are done. `series` as defined in cltl2 represent how to compute a sequence of values but do not store them. The typical use of a series is to consume the values it produces. If one wants to keep values around then put them in an array for faster lookup.

Comment: @DanRobertson right. but that's not the whole picture, because in addition to being automatically memoized which isn't such a big deal as you point out, it is also automatically *extendable* i.e. pausable and restartable at/from an arbitrary point in sequence. I don't know, whether such ability exists in the series facility? From a cursory look over the CLtL2 chapter, it seems not. if so, *this* might be the advantage, the *reason* that you asked about.

Comment: @WillNess that’s a good point. I can’t find any way to restart in the middle of a series, although I think it ought to be possible (but possibly reliant on implementation specific details). A key question is whether the internal state is immutable. I think it is but great lengths are taken to make it feel mutable.

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution would be to use the [LOOP](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html) macro of Common Lisp, e.g.:

```
(print
    (loop for x in '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
      for y = (pellse x)
      collect y))
```

That prints out the following result:

```
(1 2 5 12 29 70 169)
```

Based on this, you can build the following function:

```
(defun list-of-n-pell-numbers (n)
    (loop for x from 0 to n
          for y = (pellse x)
          collect y))
```

And run it like the following:

```
(print (list-of-n-pell-numbers 7))
(0 1 2 5 12 29 70 169)
```

But please be careful when using this code, because your definition of `pellse` function is recursive, and has the risk of a stack overflow: make it call itself repeatedly enough (e.g. for big values of N), and it might blow up the call stack, unless you do some tail recursion. You might want to check the following explanations:

- http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lcl50/aug/aug-51.html
- https://0branch.com/notes/tco-cl.html

Comment: `(list-of-n-pell-numbers 7)` returns the first 8, rather than 7, Pell numbers. You could use `(loop :for x :below n :collect (pellse x))` instead.

Comment: If `pellse` were linear this would be inefficiently quadratic but as it is already exponential I guess this doesn’t really matter.