# (Lisp program) Create a list of Pell numbers using iterative approach

Tags: recursion, iteration, common-lisp, recurrence

I'm working on a lisp function that takes an input `n` and generates a list of Pell numbers till the nth number. `(pellse 7)` returns a list `(0 1 2 5 12 29 70 169)`.

Right now I only know how to define it using recursion. Can someone show me how to do it using iterative approach? Thank you.

```
(defun pellse (k) 
    (if (or (zerop k) (= k 1)) 
        k 
        (+ (* 2 (pellse (- k 1))) 
           (pellse (- k 2))))) 

(defun print_pell_list (n) 
    (loop for x from 0 to n 
          for y = (pellse x) 
          collect y))
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you please edit you question and reformat your code from single line to more readable multi-line? Also better tags would be `common lisp` (lisp is a family of languages, there is no implementation called lisp), and something like `iteration` or `iterative loop`. Oh and we don't know what you don't know, so can you please post what did you try and where did you stuck? If you don't understand iterative loops at all, we can't help you (too broad), but there is a lot of materials on this topic on the net, just use your favourite search engine.

Comment: Actually what I should start with is - why did you ask about something you were given in you previous question? What is wrong with the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223694/how-can-i-generate-series-of-pell-numbers-instead-of-a-specific-one-in-lisp ? Voting to close as duplicate.